# How to calculate minimum MaxHeapSize for JVM when allocating just 1 array?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

Given :

```
static final int SIZE=2*1024*1024;
public static void main(String[] a) {
    int[] i = new int[SIZE];
}
```

2M * 4 (bytes for int) = 8Mb (+ maybe 4mb for metaspace, no?)

Running JVM with 12Mb heap size  `-Xmx12m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`
I'm getting pretty nice
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
But when I increase the heap up to 13Mb it runs just fine.

Looking at values of `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` how can I calculate the exact minimal maximum heap threshold which allows to run that snippet without Error? (with 99% probability, without any error at least for several seconds)

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I would not expect this to be realistically predictable.  JVM overhead will vary unpredictably from version to version.

Comment: MB = Megabyte, Mb = Megabit, mb = milli-bits.

Comment: Another calculation is how much is your time worth in MBs. If you are on *minimum wage in the UK*, one minute of your time is worth 48 MB. If you spend more than one minute thinking about 48 MB you might have spent too long on it. You might also be costing your company or your time is worth more than minimum wage.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allocating a large block of primitives like this, I would use direct memory.  `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SIZE * 4).asIntBuffer();` This use almost no heap regardless of the size.

In terms of looking at the heap required I would ignore anything less than a few 100 MB of overhead unless you know this is an issues.  100 MB is worth about 2 minutes of your time and it's probably not an efficient use of your time worrying about it.

However, in general you need 4 bytes for an int element in an array, with some overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Try the runtime object to know, see this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Answer (score 1):

The JVM uses copying, generational collectors. A large object (large relative to the heap size) will be directly allocated in the old generation, which means you will still need some extra space for the young generation (eden + survivor 1 & 2). Their sizes will depend on the collector used and various tuning knobs.

Additionally the array will not be the only object that gets allocated. Simply creating a class and running `main()` will pull in a minimal set of JRE classes such as `Class`, `Classloader`, `String`, `Thread` and more. You have to take a heap dump on an empty program to assess what exactly gets loaded.

In practice attempting to calculate the absolute minimum would just be asking for trouble in case you made any tiny misprediction about JVM behavior in your calculation. A safer approach would be to measure memory behavior given various input sizes and then adding some safety margin and also vetting your algorithms for potential pathological behaviors where the memory consumption scales worse than the average case.